# Easy script to uncomment a line in squid config file

Tags: bash, scripting, raspberry-pi, squid

I am creating a script to easily uncomment and add lines to the `/etc/squid/squid.conf` file as when the squid package is installed, the line `acl allow localnet` is always commented. Is it possible to use a bash script to do this or is it easier to make a backup of that file and replace the original with the lines that I need?

Comment: What's the full original format of the line, and what's your target?

Comment: If there are only two states, one with some lines commented and one with some uncommented, then better keep two files, one named `*.conf.old` and swap them by an oneliner.

Comment: @thanasisp or keep both files and start `squid` with `-f <desired.config>`.